# How to display content from MYSQL Join if ID is not relational

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have an artist page that is supposed to show the albums released by a particular artist.

I am joining two tables to accomplish this. The relation is the `artist_name`. Both the `artist` table and the `albums` tables have different IDs.

Unfortunately, the artist page is showing ALL of the album photos in the database instead of only the ones related to the artist.

My thought process was to to use the `$_GET` method to grab the artist name which would be included in the URL when the user clicks the link to visit that artist's page. But obviously, this is not working.

Here's my script:

```
$artist_name = $_GET['artist_name'];
//Query the database to show the albums
$albums =  "SELECT artist.artist_name,albums.artist_name,albums.photo,albums.album_title
            FROM artist,albums 
            WHERE  artist.artist_name=albums.artist_name
            ORDER BY year_released ASC"; 

$q = $db->query($albums);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

html:

```
 <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
                    <span class="margin-two album">

                        <img src="http://mywebsite.com/albums/<?php echo $r['photo']; ?>" alt="picture of the album <?php echo $r['album_title']; ?> by <?php echo $r['artist_name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $r['album_title']; ?>"  \>


                    </span>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

How can I output the correct albums for each artist?

Comment: You're not using your `$artist_name` variable. Include it in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Why don't you use a JOIN ? That is exactly what JOINs do. That's what they're made for. Use them accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Fred-ii-. My WHERE clause not looks like this: ` WHERE  artist.$artist_name=albums.$artist_name` but now I am getting this message `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'artist.jodeci' in 'where clause''`

Comment: @JohannesHahn The OP is using a JOIN

Comment: @Soletwosole Note that this syntax was effectively rendered obsolete way back in 1995. Consider using proper JOIN syntax instead. It's clearer, easier to maintain/amend, and less prone to error.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you. I did not know that. I appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for pointing me in the right direction with MYSQL `LEFT JOIN`. After doing a bit more research, I got the following code to work by adding `USING` in my script.

```
$artist_name = $_GET['artist_name'];

//Query the database to show the albums
$albums = "SELECT * FROM artist
          LEFT JOIN albums 
          USING (artist_name) 
          WHERE artist_name='$artist_name'
          ORDER BY year_released";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query with left join to `albums` table.

```
$artist_name = $_GET['artist_name'];
//Query the database to show the albums
$albums =  "SELECT artist.artist_name,albums.artist_name,albums.photo,albums.album_title
            FROM artist,albums 
            LEFT JOIN 
            albums on albums.artist_name = artist.artist_name
            WHERE  artist.artist_name=$artist_name
            ORDER BY year_released ASC"; 

$q = $db->query($albums);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: I get this error when I use the code you provided: `Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'albums''`

Comment: To get a working query, first try a static query with some prefilled value in something like phpMyAdmin.  Also, $artist_name probably needs to be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Change your $albums string to :

```
$albums = "SELECT artist.artist_name, albums.photo, albums.album_title
           FROM artist
           LEFT JOIN albums ON (artist.artist_name=albums.artist_name) 
           WHERE artist.artist_name=$artist_name
           ORDER BY year_released ASC";
```